# Number.IsNaN and not categorizing variable*number properly?

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to make the script recognize bad input and give no output
If I put any number each time I input something it runs the function Myfunction.
The function returns output in textarea id=t as the number inputted followed by the same number * 100 and *1000. When the input area id=1 is blank it triggers if statement as true because it checks isNaN which a blank area is, the value of id=t is then changed to blank, when I add just a letter or multiple letters to textarea id=1 it shows no input as it should. However if I input a number followed by any combination of letters in textarea id=1 it first updates output to match the number, then when the letters are typed the output doesn't change and is equal to that of inputting just the number before the letters, isNan doesn't register it as 1 and typeof doesn't register it as not a number type.
Why does this break, How do I fix this?

```
<!-- Unit converter iteration 2 -->
<head>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Input uses oninput event to execute function-->
<textarea type="number" oninput="return myFunction()" id="1" name="1" value="" rows="1" cols="30"></textarea><br>

<textarea readonly id="t" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
<script type=  "application/javascript">
    /*Instead of throwing alert if N is NaN, it doesn't show any output instead */
    function myFunction(){
        var N = parseInt(document.getElementById("1").value);
        if (Number.isNaN(N) || typeof(N) != "number" ){
            document.getElementById("t").value = "";}

        else {
            /* Outputs same variables as in iteration 1 but now the html form is textarea*/
            var m = N;
            var cm = m * 100;
            var mm = m * 1000;
            document.getElementById("t").value = ""+m+" "+cm+" "+mm;}
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read the documentation for parseInt...

Comment: @ASDFGerte Not it isn't. `Number.isNaN(NaN)` will return `true` even though `typeof(NaN) != "number"` will return `false`. But `Number.isNaN("5")` will return `false` and `typeof("foo") != "number"` will return `false`.

Comment: @nickzoum `N` comes from a `parseInt` the line above, therefore your case cannot happen, however, it's true, that the way i worded it was not good. Btw, you probably meant '`typeof("foo") != "number"` will return `true`'.

Answer (score 0):

That's just because of how `parseInt` works. Let's focus on this part of your code:

```
var N = parseInt(document.getElementById("1").value);
        if (Number.isNaN(N) || typeof(N) != "number" ){
            document.getElementById("t").value = "";}
```

When `parseInt` is called on a string that starts with a number followed by characters (e.g. `123abc`), the function will return the numbers as an integer (`123` in the previous example).

Example:

```js
num = parseInt('123abc');
console.log(num);
```